# Python dict easiest and cleanest way to get value of key2 if key1 is not present

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a python dict like this,

```
d = {
"k1" : "v1",
"k2" : "v2"
}
```

I want to pick up value of k1 from dict, which I can do like this,

```
d.get("k1")
```

But the problem is, sometimes k1 will be absent in the dict. In that case, I want to pick k2 from the dict. I do it like this now

```
val = d.get("k1", None)
if not val:
    val = d.get("k2", None)
```

I can do like this as well,

```
if "k1" in d:
    val = d['k1']
else:
    val = d.get("k2", None)
```

These solutions look okay and works as expected, I was wondering if there exists a one-liner solution to this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### A `d.get` inside a `d.get`:

Maybe try a double `dict.get`:

```
val = d.get("k1", d.get("k2", None))
```

And now:

```
print(val)
```

Would give `k1`'s value if there is a `k1` and `k2`'s value if there isn't a key named `k1`, but if there also isn't a `k2`, it gives `None`.

My code does a `d.get`, but inside the parameters the second argument you did `None`, in this case we do another `d.get`, which is for `k2`, and in the second `d.get` it finally has the second argument as `None`, it only gives `None` if both of the keys are not in `d`.

**Edit:**

If there are more keys (i.e. `k3`, `k4` ...), just add more `d.get`s:

```
val = d.get("k1", d.get("k2", d.get("k3", d.get("k4"))))
```

And just add a:

```
print(val)
```

To output it.

### Using a generator with `next`:

You could also use a generator with `next` to get the first value, like this:

```
val = next((d[i] for i in ['k1', 'k2', 'k3', 'k4'...] if i in d), None)
```

And now:

```
print(val)
```

Would also give the right result.

Remember to add a `None` so that if there aren't any values from any of those keys it won't give a `StopIteration`.

Comment: Liked this one. It will get quite complex if I have 10 or 20 keys I want to search for. I was looking for something like ```d.get(["k1", "k2", "k3"], None)``` -- Where it will look for k1, if not found look for k2 and so on.

Comment: Just a point about efficiency - the one-liner will look up all four keys even if the first one is present.

Comment: @SreeramTP Yeah unfortunately there is no such a thing for dictionaries :(

Comment: I think I have to iteratively seach for all keys

Comment: @SreeramTP I added another way of doing a generator, please check it out

Comment: @SreeramTP I did another way ;)

Comment: @kaya3 I have another way in my answer now!

Comment: I liked th generator based solution. That is cool

Comment: @SreeramTP Yeah it's much easier than all these `d.get`s :)

Answer (score 7):

The `None` in `d.get()` specifies what to do if nothing is found.

Simply add another `d.get()` instead of `None`.

```
d.get('k1', d.get('k2', None))
#'v1'
```

Comment: I liked the idea of nesting get. But it can get quite complex if I want to search for 20 or so keys.

Answer (score 2):

If there's no built-in function which does what you want, then you can write your own; you only have to write it once, and then everywhere else that you actually use it, it's a one-liner.

```py
def get_alt(d, *keys, default=None):
    return next((d[k] for k in keys if k in d), default)
```

Examples:

```py
>>> my_dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
>>> get_alt(my_dict, 'a', 'b', 'c')
1
>>> get_alt(my_dict, 'd', 'b', 'c')
2
>>> get_alt(my_dict, 'd', 'e', 'c')
3
>>> get_alt(my_dict, 'd', 'e', 'f') is None
True
>>> get_alt(my_dict, 'd', 'e', 'f', default=4)
4
```

Comment: Ooh same as my second way +1 :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
val = d.get("k1") or d.get("k2")
```

This is equivalent to your *"I do it like this now"* solution. `None` is the `get`'s default, no need to specify it. And unlike the nested `get`s posted by others, this doesn't execute both `get`s if the first one succeeds.